# LoT Heading in the second page of my intro

Tags: header-footer

I got LoT heading in the second page of intro . How can I resolve the problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{emptypage}


%-------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\changefont \slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\changefont \thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%-------------------------------

%-------------------------------

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter 
    \tableofcontents
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Indice}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indice}

    \listoffigures
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{Lista delle Figure}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista delle Figure}

    \listoftables
    \renewcommand\listtablename{Lista delle Tabelle}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista delle Tabelle}


    \mainmatter
    \chapter*{Introduzione}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}

    \lipsum[1]

    \bigskip

    \lipsum[2]

    \bigskip

    \lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: any help? maybe there is something not clear in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\markboth{Introduzione}{}` after `\chapter*{Introduzione}`; a complete example (I also moved the redefinitions for the predefined names to the preamble using `\addto\captionsitalian`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\addto\captionsitalian{%
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Indice}
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{Lista delle Figure}
    \renewcommand\listtablename{Lista delle Tabelle}
}

%-------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\changefont \slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\changefont \thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%-------------------------------

%-------------------------------

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Indice}
    \tableofcontents

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista delle Figure}
    \listoffigures

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista delle Tabelle}
    \listoftables

    \mainmatter
    \chapter*{Introduzione}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}
    \markboth{Introduzione}{}
    \lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about writing a canonical Q+A "How to get correct headers for unnumbered chapters and include them in the ToC?"

Comment: @lockstep Good idea. I can do so in some hours (or perhaps do you want to write it?).

Comment: I'd also need some time to think about possible corner cases, so you go ahead. :-) (And if you don't mention KOMA-Script's `\addchap`, I can still write an additional answer.)